# Android Firebase Cloud Messaging Issue - Only works when I disconnect/reconnect to internet in App

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am developing an application at the moment that is utilizing firebase-cloud-messaging to receive data payloads.

If I restart the device and launch the application data payloads do not come through. How ever if I put the emulator in airplane mode and then connect it back to the internet all of the data comes through.

From that point on the application receives data payloads without flaw even after restarting the application or reinstalling it.

The issue just persists when the device is restarted and on first launch it seems to not receive data. Until I do the disconnect and reconnect to internet trick.

I am handling the data payload in the onRecieve method and when it works it works consistently for a long time. But requires me to reconnect to the internet manually to get the cloud messaging to work.

Any ideas?

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        //I handle the data payload in here
}
```

Comment: You mention device and also emulator. An emulator is not a device. So which is it? Are you testing on a real physical device or on an emulator? Please beware that testing FCM with an emulator is not representative of how a real device will react to messages. With messaging you should always test on a real physical device.

Comment: Hi sorry yes I am using an emulator not a real device

Comment: I tried it on a real device and still the same issue. I feel like it has something to do with the token or instance. But  I dont understand why it would only when i reconnect to he internet and no other time